# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined

Tags: class, forms, extjs, grid, extjs4

im pretty new to extjs and having trouble with it

i am using the [browser-layout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) example for my application

im trying to add a [form grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/form/form-grid.html) to it
i defined a new class but when i call my form grid i get this error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined**

here is my code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.app.myFormGrid', {

extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.formgrid ',
myData: [
    ['3m Co', 71.72, 0.02, 0.03, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Alcoa Inc', 29.01, 0.42, 1.47, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Altria Group Inc', 83.81, 0.28, 0.34, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American Express Company', 52.55, 0.01, 0.02, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American International Group, Inc.', 64.13, 0.31, 0.49, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['AT&T Inc.', 31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Boeing Co.', 75.43, 0.53, 0.71, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Caterpillar Inc.', 67.27, 0.92, 1.39, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['United Technologies Corporation', 63.26, 0.55, 0.88, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Verizon Communications', 35.57, 0.39, 1.11, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.', 45.45, 0.73, 1.63, '9/1 12:00am']
],

ds: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: [
        { name: 'company' },
        { name: 'price', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'change', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'pctChange', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia' },
    // Rating dependent upon performance 0 = best, 2 = worst
        {name: 'rating', type: 'int', convert: function (value, record) {
            var pct = record.get('pctChange');
            if (pct < 0) return 2;
            if (pct < 1) return 1;
            return 0;
        } 
    }
    ],
    data: this.myData
}),


change : function (val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
    } else if (val < 0) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
    }
    return val;
},

pctChange: function (val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
    } else if (val < 0) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
    }
    return val;
},


rating: function (v) {
    if (v == 0) return "A";
    if (v == 1) return "B";
    if (v == 2) return "C";
},

initComponent: function () {
    var gridForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        id: 'company-form',
        frame: true,
        title: 'Company data',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 750,
        layout: 'column',    // Specifies that the items will now be arranged in columns

        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign: 'left',
            msgTarget: 'side'
        },

        items: [{
            columnWidth: 0.60,
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            store: this.ds,
            height: 400,
            title: 'Company Data',

            columns: [
            {
                id: 'company',
                text: 'Company',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'company'
            },
            {
                text: 'Price',
                width: 75,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'price'
            },
            {
                text: 'Change',
                width: 75,
                sortable: true,
                renderer: this.change,
                dataIndex: 'change'
            },
            {
                text: '% Change',
                width: 75,
                sortable: true,
                renderer: this.pctChange,
                dataIndex: 'pctChange'
            },
            {
                text: 'Last Updated',
                width: 85,
                sortable: true,
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                dataIndex: 'lastChange'
            },
            {
                text: 'Rating',
                width: 30,
                sortable: true,
                renderer: this.rating,
                dataIndex: 'rating'
            }
        ],

            listeners: {
                selectionchange: function (model, records) {
                    if (records[0]) {
                        this.up('form').getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            columnWidth: 0.4,
            margin: '0 0 0 10',
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Company details',
            defaults: {
                width: 240,
                labelWidth: 90
            },
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'company'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Price',
                name: 'price'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: '% Change',
                name: 'pctChange'
            }, {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Last Updated',
                name: 'lastChange'
            }, {
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                fieldLabel: 'Rating',
                columns: 3,
                defaults: {
                    name: 'rating' //Each radio has the same name so the browser will make sure only one is checked at once
                },
                items: [{
                    inputValue: '0',
                    boxLabel: 'A'
                }, {
                    inputValue: '1',
                    boxLabel: 'B'
                }, {
                    inputValue: '2',
                    boxLabel: 'C'
                }]
            }]
        }],
        //renderTo: bd
    });


    //gridForm.child('gridpanel').getSelectionModel().select(0);

},

});
```

then in my main file , i create my form grid and add it to my tabpanel:

```
...

var myPanel =  Ext.create('Ext.app.myFormGrid',{title : 'panel 2',height:250});

...

xtype : 'tabpanel',

...
```

thanks for ur time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

first, you need to define a class, in this class you will put the "var formGrid" from example, only that. All the other stuff, myData, and logics are going to be in a separate file. Then you will say in items, "Create"  the class that you have defined. So, not all data from example is going to be in class(define), but only the panel with the grid. I try this and it works for me.

here:   first file(class)

```
Ext.define("app.formGrid",{
    extend:"Ext.form.Panel",
    id: 'company-form',
    frame: true,
    title: 'Company data',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 750,
    layout: 'column',    // Specifies that the items will now be arranged in columns

    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'left',
        msgTarget: 'side'
    },

    items: [{
        columnWidth: 0.60,
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        store: ds,
        height: 400,
        title:'Company Data',

        columns: [
            {
                id       :'company',
                text   : 'Company',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'company'
            },
            {
                text   : 'Price',
                width    : 75,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'price'
            },
            {
                text   : 'Change',
                width    : 75,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : change,
                dataIndex: 'change'
            },
            {
                text   : '% Change',
                width    : 75,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : pctChange,
                dataIndex: 'pctChange'
            },
            {
                text   : 'Last Updated',
                width    : 85,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                dataIndex: 'lastChange'
            },
            {
                text: 'Rating',
                width: 30,
                sortable: true,
                renderer: rating,
                dataIndex: 'rating'
            }
        ],

        listeners: {
            selectionchange: function(model, records) {
                if (records[0]) {
                    this.up('form').getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        columnWidth: 0.4,
        margin: '0 0 0 10',
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title:'Company details',
        defaults: {
            width: 240,
            labelWidth: 90
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'company'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Price',
            name: 'price'
        },{
            fieldLabel: '% Change',
            name: 'pctChange'
        },{
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Last Updated',
            name: 'lastChange'
        }, {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            fieldLabel: 'Rating',
            columns: 3,
            defaults: {
                name: 'rating' //Each radio has the same name so the browser will make sure only one is checked at once
            },
            items: [{
                inputValue: '0',
                boxLabel: 'A'
            }, {
                inputValue: '1',
                boxLabel: 'B'
            }, {
                inputValue: '2',
                boxLabel: 'C'
            }]
        }]
    }],

});
```

second file(rest of code)

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();

var bd = Ext.getBody();

// sample static data for the store
var myData = [
    ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02,  0.03,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42,  1.47,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28,  0.34,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31,  0.49,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Boeing Co.',                          75.43, 0.53,  0.71,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Caterpillar Inc.',                    67.27, 0.92,  1.39,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Citigroup, Inc.',                     49.37, 0.02,  0.04,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51,  1.28,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Exxon Mobil Corp',                    68.1,  -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['General Electric Company',            34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['General Motors Corporation',          30.27, 1.09,  3.74,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',                 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Honeywell Intl Inc',                  38.77, 0.05,  0.13,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Intel Corporation',                   19.88, 0.31,  1.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['International Business Machines',     81.41, 0.44,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Johnson & Johnson',                   64.72, 0.06,  0.09,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',              45.73, 0.07,  0.15,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['McDonald\'s Corporation',             36.76, 0.86,  2.40,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Merck & Co., Inc.',                   40.96, 0.41,  1.01,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Microsoft Corporation',               25.84, 0.14,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Pfizer Inc',                          27.96, 0.4,   1.45,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['The Coca-Cola Company',               45.07, 0.26,  0.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['The Home Depot, Inc.',                34.64, 0.35,  1.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['The Procter & Gamble Company',        61.91, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['United Technologies Corporation',     63.26, 0.55,  0.88,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Verizon Communications',              35.57, 0.39,  1.11,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',               45.45, 0.73,  1.63,  '9/1 12:00am']
];

var ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'company'},
        {name: 'price',      type: 'float'},
        {name: 'change',     type: 'float'},
        {name: 'pctChange',  type: 'float'},
        {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'},
        // Rating dependent upon performance 0 = best, 2 = worst
        {name: 'rating', type: 'int', convert: function(value, record) {
            var pct = record.get('pctChange');
            if (pct < 0) return 2;
            if (pct < 1) return 1;
            return 0;
        }}
    ],
    data: myData
});


// example of custom renderer function
function change(val){
    if(val > 0){
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
    }else if(val < 0){
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
    }
    return val;
}
// example of custom renderer function
function pctChange(val){
    if(val > 0){
        return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
    }else if(val < 0){
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
    }
    return val;
}

// render rating as "A", "B" or "C" depending upon numeric value.
function rating(v) {
    if (v == 0) return "A";
    if (v == 1) return "B";
    if (v == 2) return "C";
}


bd.createChild({tag: 'h2', html: 'Using a Grid with a Form'});

/*
 * Here is where we create the Form
 */



gridForm.child('gridpanel').getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

and the Ext.create in your main View:
...

```
    items:[Ext.create("app.formGrid",{
            })]
```

Just to explain why I have sead that before: [HERE!](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/class_system)

```
II. Naming Conventions

1) Classes

  Classes that are not distributed by Sencha should never use Ext as the top-level namespace.
```

Comment: but this is a separate file, my main file is the layout-browser.js and i need to add this (and others) in the tabs i have in it . the ext.app because i based my code of the portlet in the portal example. feel free to ask me other questions if its not clair and please bare with me im really new to all this and cant get hold of it

Comment: i dont know about ext.app bu its working, already done it with simple panel and simple grid

Comment: how do i connect  the second file with the first one? i mean where do i call the second file?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="app/test.js"></script>

Comment: simply use html, your class will load dinamicaly and the rest of the code manually.

Comment: thanks , i get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createChild' of null**

Comment: i have tired this, it works. Maybe your bug is sommwhere else. Try to debuggit!

Comment: found the code causing the error and removed it,anyway it wasnt necessary.  do u know what this does :  gridForm.child('gridpanel').getSelectionModel().select(0);

Comment: help on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328355/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-compile-of-undefined) please,thx

Comment: Downvote because these are all nice suggestions, but are not the source of the problem. The real problem is that the OP forgot to call `this.callParent()` from their `initComponent`

Answer (score 10):

You can also get this error if you define a component's `initComponent` function without calling `this.callParent(arguments);` inside of it.

Clearly that wasn't the case for you but just pointing this out for others.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer has good information, but shows a bad style of setting config (putting them on the prototype) but this is the real problem. I stil forget to call `this.callParent()` way too often when overriding inherited methods.