# How to use Ext.define in EXTJS4

Tags: extjs4

I get a error:dockedItems is null or not a object.
I want to know what I should do when I define a class that define an EXTJS4 class.

```
Ext.define("com.yx.MyPanel", {
                extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
                config: {
                    title: "Clannad",
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100
                },
                constructor: function(config) {
                    this.initConfig(config);
                    this.callParent([config]);
                }
            });
            Ext.create("com.yx.MyPanel", {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use ext.define in extjs4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290729/how-to-use-ext-define-in-extjs4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have explained how to use Ext.define in ExtJS4 in bellowed link.

[How to use Ext.define in ExtJS 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290729/how-to-use-ext-define-in-extjs4/6455079#6455079)