# How to Extend our own class in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs4

I have created the class in Ext JS 4, and now I want to extend that in another class. I use `extend` properties, to extend the class. But I am not able to extend the class. Do I want to use require to include the class file. But I keep both the files in the same directory.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290729/how-to-use-ext-define-in-extjs4/6455079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define source paths for ExtJS to locate your source files.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true,
            paths: {
                '[your namespace prefix here]': '[physical path]'
            }
        });
```

Then define `Ext.require` or `requires` section in subclass to enable automatic path resolution.
Read [this link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader) for more info.

**Example**

Base class: file located at folder `root/view/common/Picker.js`

```
Ext.define('RL.view.common.Picker', {
    extend: "Ext.form.field.Picker",
...
}
```

Sub class: file located at folder `root/view/selection/DriverTreeCombo.js`

```
Ext.define('RL.view.selection.DriverTreeCombo', {
        extend: "RL.view.common.Picker",
        requires: ['Ext.tree.Panel', 'RL.view.common.TreeBase'],
...
}
```

I have namespace as RL.xxx.xxx and RL is supposed to be the `root` folder. Now I can define Loader configuration as below

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true,
            paths: {
                'RL': '/root'                    
            }
        })
```

Loader configuration should be set before 'Ext.onReady(...)' function call. Going through examples folder in ExtJS package would help you to see how this is done.

**Further reading:**

- [The Class System](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/class_system)
- [Dynamic Loading and new class system](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system)

Comment: Thank you.. But where exactly we want to use this code. We have to create a seperate file, or can write in the js file, where we extend our own class file?

Comment: Hey colombo, Could you send me the fully functional code for this. Im not able to do it, it shows 'Exception Thrown and not caught' error.

Comment: I have edited my answer again. See the Further reading links at the end. It will help.

Comment: You will find a downloadable ZIP file with a example at the end of Dynamic Loading and New class system page.